# ¿Por qué me aparece NULL en las columnas en lugar de datos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data, null, datos

Trato de obtener una tabla que sea parecida a esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar el siguiente query, lo que obtengo es una tabla con datos NULL, algo que no quisiera obtener. ¿Podrían ayudarme a saber donde está el error?

```
SELECT authors.au_id 'AUTHOR ID', authors.au_lname 'LAST NAME', authors.au_fname 'FIRST NAME', titles.title_id 'TITLE', publishers.pub_name 'PUBLISHERS'  
FROM authors 
LEFT JOIN titleauthor 
ON authors.au_id = titleauthor.au_id 
LEFT JOIN titles 
ON titleauthor.au_id = titles.title_id 
LEFT JOIN publishers 
ON titles.title_id = publishers.pub_id 
GROUP BY authors.au_id 
ORDER BY 'AUTHOR ID', 'LAST NAME', 'FIRST NAME', 'TITLE', 'PUBLISHERS';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El origen de esos `NULL` los veo por esta zona:

```
ON titleauthor.au_id = titles.title_id 
ON titles.title_id = publishers.pub_id
```

Parece que estás conectando tablas por los campos incorrectos. Tendrás que buscar en la tabla `titleauthor`  algo similar al `title_id` y reescribir el `ON` como:

```
ON titleauthor.title_id = titles.title_id
```

Y lo mismo con:

```
ON titles.pub_id = publishers.pub_id
```

Como, sin la estructura de tus tablas, no puedo saber cómo has llamado exactamente a esos campos, lo mejor es que modifiques la pregunta aportando el dataset con phpMyAdmin, Exportar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente tenía equivocados los nombres de los campos.